# Xcode could not launch app. Process launch failed: 4294967295

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I'm developing an iOS 8 app in Xcode 6.0.1 and running it on my iPhone 5 (which has iOS 8.0.2 on it). Before I updated to iOS 8.0.1 and Xcode 6.0.1, I never got the error I'm getting. However, now, sometimes when I try to run my app from Xcode onto my iPhone, this error message pops down from the top of the Xcode window:

```
Could not launch "[app name]". Process launch failed: 4294967295
```

It appears that this error only occurs when I first run the app from Xcode onto my device (i.e. if I close the error message in Xcode, but I don't close the app on my phone--so the app's still up on my phone--I don't get this error when I click the run button again in Xcode). However, there doesn't seem to be a whole lot of consistency because sometimes the error message doesn't drop down even when I launch the app onto my phone for the first time from Xcode (i.e. without the app already being up on my phone).

Also, I have tried several solutions, none of which have completely fixed the error:

1. Clean out the build, clear out DerivedData, restart my mac, and reopen Xcode.
2. Get a new certificate for the app from apple after accepting their new iOS 8.0 license agreement.
3. Make sure that, when I install 3rd party Cocoa pods, the Podfile specifies iOS 8.0 platform.
4. Set the app's deployment target and build settings for iOS 8.0

I can't seem to figure out how to get this error to consistently stay away even after trying the above-mentioned solution attempts. Again, I can still run the app on my phone normally sometimes, but every couple of runs it displays the strange error message in Xcode and only opens the app on my phone but won't link it with Xcode (for console output, etc).

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I'm having the same error as you. I've checked my provisioning profiles, code signing and also that I'm compiling for Debug but nothing seems to fix the problem. Did you find any solution to this? In my code, I'm calling a huge C source code and, the error disappears when I comment some function calls, but I don't know why. I didn't found anything special inside the functions.

Comment: In case it helps you. My problem was that I was defining a huge array in the C code: `integer big_array[150000000]`. The required memory for this array was reserved when launching the application and the iPad run out of memory. Making it smaller fix my problem.

Comment: Thanks. I only have the issue occasionally and rather inconsistently. It seems to have mostly gone away now.

Comment: I'm just doing some basic stuff with Security.framework (keychain).

Answer (score 26):

We have encountered this before.
The cause was we were using Distribution provisioning profile on Development.

You need to use a Development provisioning profile if you want the debugger to link to your XCode.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. My provisioning profile is in fact a Developer one. However, it looks like the "Don't code sign" option was selected in the code signing section for my project's build settings, although the "iOS Developer" option was selected under the code signing section for the target build settings. I didn't catch that before, but I just fixed it. I'll accept your answer up once I know I'm not having any more problems with this. Thanks so much!

Comment: The error just came up again in the same way as I described in the question, even though I'm using a Developer provisioning profile and all my code signing is set to "iOS Developer". I tried restarting my iPhone, which fixed it for now, but it might come up again. Any other suggestions?

Comment: The error came up again, so restarting the iPhone didn't help.

Comment: Was pulling my hair out last night... walked away, slept and searched this morning.  Yea SO and gmarintes.  Thanks!

Comment: For me the only solution was the factory reset of the iPhone 5S. :(

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried disconnecting the device and rebooting it?

When I have seen this, the app was always running, but Xcode was not able to attach the debugger to the process (or attach it quickly enough.)

Comment: After following the suggestion from @gmarintes (as I described in my comments), the error seemed to be fixed. Then it broke again later, but restarting my iPhone has helped for now. Any other suggestions so this doesn't happen again? Usually restarting doesn't permanently fix things.

Comment: I try to run as few apps as possible while testing. Also unlock the phone if necessary before hitting 'run' in Xcode. And it helps to run fewer apps on the Mac.

Answer (score 0):

For me the fix was opening the Device Manager (Window -> Devices) and deleting the installed app (select the app and click the "-" button). On the next run the error went away.

XCode 7.3.1