# Could not launch "myApp" Xcode

Tags: xcode

I have this error when i'm trying to run my cpp file: "Could not launch "DND"

After reading several topics about this problem, I turn to you because I have not been able to solve it. Delete the derived data does not work. This happened after a clean (Product -> Clean)

[Could not launch "MyApp"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3KXR.png)

My error: "error: executable doesn't exist"

My project is not on a iOS device.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26287451/8560567) might help.

Comment: thanks you for your help but i'm not using app iOS just a project in c++

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by adding my cpp file manually in my project:

1. Click on your project.xcodeproj in the Navigator
2. "TARGETS" -> "Build Phases" and add your cpp files needed in "Compile Sources"