# "Unable to launch" on Xcode when i build my code on my iPhone

Tags: xcode

my code works on simulator but it doesn't work on real device with a message

> Unable to launch

i want to play my code on my iPhone but i don't know how because i'm a beginner

please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26287365

Answer (score 0):

it happened to me too, it happened probably because i deleted the app from the phone maybe while running xcode, and xcode is afterwards confused and denies to install and run the app with the message "unable to launch" the solution is hold Alt key and press the Run button then you select specifically the app you want to run (i had there "Ask on launch") after this, the message unable to launch disappeared (and app was installed on phone though) but another message returned "iphone denied the request" so then i again returned "ask on launch" and it worked again.